# AttributeConverter Date String

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

Is it possible to create `AttributeConverter<Date,String>`? I want to use it in a Spring project with Hibernate.
I want to convert `String` dataColumn to `Date` entity attribute.
Please help me.
It is well placed in package than is scanned by hibernate

```
@Converter(autoApply=true)
public class DatetoStringConverter implements AttributeConverter
{
    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(Date arg0) {
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy",Locale.FRENCH);
        return formatter.format(arg0);
    }

    @Override
    public Date convertToEntityAttribute(String arg0) {
        try {
            SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy",Locale.FRENCH);
            return  formatter.parse(arg0);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

and the field

```
@Column(name="Date")
@DateTimeFormat(pattern="dd/MM/yyyy")
@Convert(converter=DatetoStringConverter.class)
private Date datefonction;
```

Comment: you can use data transformer

Answer (score 3):

Define the converter:

```
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class MyDateAttributeConverter implements AttributeConverter<Date, String> {

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(Date entityDate) {
        // format entityDate and return String
    }

    @Override
    public Date convertToEntityAttribute(String databaseDate) {
        // parse databaseDate and return Date object
    }
}
```

Apply converter to the desired field in your entity:

```
@Convert(converter = MyDateAttributeConverter.class)
private Date date;
```

Just make sure that the @AttribureConverter is placed in a package than is scanned by hibernate (session factory property).

Comment: It is well placed in  package than is scanned by hibernate

Comment: that is scanned.. typo

Comment: can you help me i have error message Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Error attempting to apply AttributeConverte

Comment: have you added null checks?