# How to Convert Cassandra text column to java.util.date

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-cassandra

I had a Cassandra table item where end_date is of text type and I had end_date as java.util.date in java so I’m having error while retrieving data from dB i’m Using spring jpa please let me know what should I change

Answer (score 0):

You will have to implement a custom converter between String and Date. Refer to answers in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43044121/attributeconverter-date-string) for code sample.